# Import text file of integers with commas and tabs into java array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file that looks like the following:

```
1    2,1    3,5    4
2    1,1    4,2    3,1
3    1,5    4,1    0
4    3,1    2,2    1,3
```

I want to separate the text file into two arrays so that the first array is only the numbers before the comma and the second array is only the numbers following the comma.  The groups of numbers are separated by tabs.  The output here should be:

```
array1 = {{1,2,3,4},{2,1,4,3},{3,1,4,0},{4,3,2,1}};
array2 = {{0,1,5,0},{0,1,2,1},{0,5,1,0},{0,1,2,3}};
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see no logic to get those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read each line individually and use a StringTokenizer to get the next pairs.

First, count the number of lines in the input (n) and then the number of pairs in each line (m). Here, n = 4, m = 4.

```
int[][] array1 = new int[n][m];
int[][] array2 = new int[n][m];
```

then, read in the input with StringTokenizer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    StringTokenizer line = new StringTokenizer(read line here);
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        String next = line.nextToken(); //next pair
        String[] values = next.split(","); //split pair by comma
        array1[n][m] = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        if (values.length == 2) { //in case there is no comma
            array2[n][m] = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's giving me the following error:  Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method split(java.lang.String)
  location: variable line of type java.util.StringTokenizer

Comment: fixed, put line instead of next haha